NGINX returns 404 for the image files with extension but renders without extension
I'm using active storage to upload files and using nginx for the request routing. I have added file upload functionality in my application which was working fine when using S3. Now I have switched to the local storage folder. NGINX is serving PDF files but not image files. If I remove the extension from the URL generated by active storage then it works fine. I'm not able to figure out what I have done wrong with NGINX. If anyone have faced the similar issue then please do let me know. Here is my nginx configuration block
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name mysite.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com.au/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com.au/privkey.pem;

    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;
    #ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    #ssl_ciphers 'TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:AEAD-AES256-GCM-SHA384:AEAD-AES128-GCM-SHA256';
    #ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    root /home/deployer/www/mysite/current/public;

    error_page 503 /503.html;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://puma;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        client_max_body_size 100m;
    }

    location /rails/active_storage/ {
        proxy_pass http://puma;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    location = /503.html {
        internal;
    }

    location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|js|css|bmp|swf|txt|xml|svg|ttf|woff)$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        expires 24h;
    }
 location @proxy {
        proxy_pass http://puma;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}


I managed to get it fixed by allowing all extensions in the location of assets block.
